# What really happens inside equals(), hashcode() and compare() method?

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I am really confused over the implementation of hashcode() and equals() method.
Here is peace of code.

```
class Employee {

      int id;
      String name;

      public Employee(int id, String name) {
          super();
          this.id = id;
          this.name = name;
      }

        @Override
       public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 3;
        int result = 1;
        result = (prime * result) + id;
        result = (prime * result) + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
     } 

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;

              if (this == obj)
                    return true;

              if (obj == null)
                    return false;
              if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;

              if (id != other.id)
                return false;
              if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                            return false;
                } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                          return false;
                return true;
        }

    }
```

[edit 1]**Doubt1**   : what every comparision really mean?

Now I have implemented comparator interface and its method.

```
  class EmpNameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
        @Override
       public int compare(Employee a, Employee b) {
              return a.name.compareToIgnoreCase(b.name);
       }
  }
```

[edit 2] **Doubt2:**  is it going to compare two adjusent objects from List<> or something else is happening, what does it do internally?

Comment: "I am really confused" is a state of mind, not a question.  If you want help here you have to formulate a precise question.  If you can not do so, this is not the site for you. You might do better consulting a book and your teacher.

Comment: Please post the part of the code where you use lists.

Comment: I didn't use it anywhere, It is just for the understanding purpose. considering I am doing employeeList.sort(); how does really compare() behaves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this == obj` checks whether the current Object is the **SAME** Object as the other one.

If they are the same Object, of course they are also "equal" .

[compareToIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) compares two `String` objects, ignoring the upper-case/lower-case differences :

> Compares two strings lexicographically, ignoring case differences.
>   This method returns an integer whose sign is that of calling compareTo
>   with normalized versions of the strings where case differences have
>   been eliminated by calling
>   Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(character)) on each
>   character.

So when you sort a list of `Employee` with your custom comparator :

```
Collections.sort(employeeList, new EmpNameComparator());
```

Two employees having the same name (ignoring different cases), will be considered the same employee for the sorting operation .

Note that you can't tell if *John* will appear before *joHn*, or the opposite.

Comment: I know compareToIgnoreCase method what is Employee a and Employee b in comparison with list I am going to sort ?

Comment: The sorting algorithm, whatever it is, needs to compare the employees in the list to sort it. a and b are two employees of the list that the algorithm needs to compare

Answer (score 1):

> Doubt1 :So what is really happening here, I know this is referred to current to current object, why are we comparing this==obj in equals. what every comparision really mean?

When you do `this == obj`, you basically check whether the reference of `this` object and the object under comparison i.e. `obj` is same or not.

If you are calling `equals()` then it is comparing whether `this` object and the object under comparison i.e. `obj` are same or not based on the `equals()` method overridden by you. For Example, `this.equals(obj)` will return `true` if and only if it satisfies the condition in the `equals()` method.

Since, you have overridden the `hashCode()` method, the hash code calculation will be done by your overridden method.

There is a contract between `hashCode()` and `equals()` and if you are overriding one then you should override other also or else it is not guaranteed to work as expected.

> Doubt2: what does that compareToIgnoreCase() means? is it going to compare two adjusent objects from List<> or something else is happening, what does it do internally?

This is just normal String comparison of the members of two object. In this case it will comapre the `name` member of the `Employee` object for Employee a and Employee b.

Unlike `compareTo()`, `compareToIgnoreCase()` makes a case insensitive comparison and will return `true` even if the case of two strings are not same. For Example,

```
fooBar
FooBAR
```

Here, `compareTo()` will return `false` but `compareToIgnoreCase()` will return `true`.

Comment: please check the edits. I mean where are the fooBar and FooBar is coming from, are these adjacent items from list? I didn't understand comparison happening in background.

Comment: That is not what == does.

Comment: @user2004685 because you have no idea what ref1 == ref2 does

Comment: When calling equals, you' re not comparing hashCodes either. This answer is still wrong

Comment: @piechuckerr When you implement `Comparator` it is likely to be called by Java while sorting the list or maybe while deciding the priority (if you are implementing PriorityQueues) etc. It is taking the 2 objects and then deciding (based on the `name` String in this case) for which one should go first.

Comment: @JBNizet Agree. I was thinking of a scenario when you insert the objects in a `HashMap` and it checks for equality.